# ViewModel not showing up in {x:Bind}

Tags: c#, xaml, binding, uwp

I have a small problem binding a TextBlock Text to a string in my view model.
I followed the guide from Microsoft but I just can´t get the hang of it.

Here is the view model class:

```
public class LoginPageViewModel
{
    public LoginPageViewModel()
    {
        title = "Space Agency";
    }

    public string title { get; set; }
}
```

The code behind:

```
public LoginPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();

        this.vm = new LoginPageViewModel();
    }

    public LoginPageViewModel vm { get; set; }
```

and the XAML:

```
<Page
x:Class="SpaceAgency.LoginPage"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:local="using:SpaceAgency"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
mc:Ignorable="d">
<Grid x:Name="rootGrid" Background="White">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <TextBlock Text="" FontSize="30" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
    <Button Content="Login" FontSize="20" Grid.Row="2" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>


</Grid>
```

The problem is the vm does not show up when using {x:Bind }.

I think I´m missing something very simple, so would be nice if you could show me the way ;)

Thanks,

CRowland

Answer (score 2):

You forgot to set the `DataContext` property in your constructor. Do that and everything works. Note that if you want your title property to update at runtime, you will have to implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` as well, but for content that is one-time your solution is just fine.

```
public sealed partial class LoginPage : Page
{
    public LoginPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        Vm = new LoginPageViewModel();
        DataContext = Vm;
    }

    public LoginPageViewModel Vm { get; set; }
}
```

Your XAML will then have IntelliSense for x:Bind

```
<TextBlock Text="{x:Bind Vm.title}" FontSize="30" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems you did not use did `x:Bind` with `Mode=OneWay`. By default, `x:Bind` has `Mode=OneTime` which doesn't update when values change. The reason that `Binding` worked is that it has a different default mode than `x:Bind`

If you first call `InitializeComponent();` and after that set the viewmodel without using Mode=, then x:Bind will not pick up the changes.

Also, if you set your viewmodel after `InitializeComponent();` (as you do), you will need to make sure the property changed event is fired for the viewmodel property, otherwise x:Bind will still not see it.

Answer (score 0):

Ok found the solution myself.

You have to add a reference to the ViewModels folder and set the DataContext in XAML.

```
<Page
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:local="using:SpaceAgency"
xmlns:ViewModels="using:SpaceAgency.ViewModels"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"

x:Class="SpaceAgency.LoginPage"
mc:Ignorable="d">
<Page.DataContext>
    <ViewModels:LoginPageViewModel/>
</Page.DataContext>
```

Now I can set the binding to the title:

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding title}" FontSize="30" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
```

This is not x:Bind but it´s fine.

Comment: even if this is working you should really consider to use the answer from @Bart - x:Bind (Compile-Time-Binding) is the new and in my opinion better solution for WPF bindings. It also speeds up the performance of your application if used properly.